# Make a pandas Boolean column that depends on two other Boolean columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Boolean columns in my data frame already, `low` and `high`. I then want to define an `in_range` column, which reflects situations where both the `low` and `high` columns in a row are false. Here's what I tried:

```
df['in_range'] = not (df.low or df.high)
```

This generates the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I want to do this on a row by row basis. I tried adding `.bool()` which results in this error:

> ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

What is wrong with my code, and what is the proper way to generate a new Boolean column based on existing Boolean columns?

Answer (score 0):

Use bitwise syntax:

```
~(df.low | df.high)
```

See [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

> Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the
>   data. The operators are: | for or, & for and, and ~ for not. These
>   **must** be grouped by using parentheses.

Using a boolean vector to index a Series works exactly as in a numpy ndarray: